# How to get culture name from a resource path file name

Tags: c#, string, file, path

Having a resource file name ex: `Employee.resx` I must get a list with other cultures in same folder. So I thought like this:

```
private void GetExtraCultures(string resxFileDirectory, string neutralResxFileName)
        {
            string resxFullPath = resxFileDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
            string[] extraResxCulturesPath = Directory.GetFiles(resxFullPath, neutralResxFileName.Replace(".resx", "") + "*" + ".resx");
            List<string> extraResxCulturesList = new List<string>();

            foreach (string extraCulturePath in extraResxCulturesPath)
            {
                string currentFileName = Path.GetFileName(extraCulturePath);
                if (currentFileName != neutralResxFileName)
                {
                    string t = currentFileName.Substring(currentFileName.IndexOf(".") + 1);
                    string tt = t.Substring(0, t.IndexOf("."));

                    extraResxCulturesList.Add(tt);
                }
            }
        }
```

Do you have any lighter solution? I am out of solution for example for how to get a string out of another. I mean, how to get `en-US` from this string `"Employee.en-US.resx"` except using substring method?
Any lighter/ better solution very much appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick'n'nasty solution: use `string.Split('.', fileName)`, then you will have an array of strings, if the array length is 3 then the middle element contains the culture (which won't always be hyphenated). If the array length is 2 then a culture wasn't specified. You could also use a regex, but that's overkill for something this simple.

Comment: You can use Path.GetExtension(Path.GetExtension(filename)) to get the "en-Us".

Comment: split method won't be more efficient comparing with what I wrote, however in the meaning time I modified a little. Then GetExtension won't help me neither because it returns a the value with dot so again I have to make a Replace or Substring.

Comment: my current code is: string tmp = string.Empty;
                    int pos;
                    if ((pos = currentFileName.IndexOf(".")) != -1)
                        tmp = currentFileName.Substring(pos + 1);
                    if ((pos = tmp.IndexOf(".")) != -1)
                        tmp = tmp.Substring(0, pos);

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
string file = @"i18n\i18n.de-DE.resx";
string culture = Path.GetExtension(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)).Substring(1);
```